# Understanding GraphQL mutation example code

Tags: javascript, graphql

I was going through the [GraphQL mutation example code](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/) on their website

In that code, they have given this code as example for mutation in the frontend

```
var author = 'andy';
var content = 'hope is a good thing';
var query = `mutation CreateMessage($input: MessageInput) {
  createMessage(input: $input) {
    id
  }
}`;

fetch('/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query,
    variables: {
      input: {
        author,
        content,
      }
    }
  })
})
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => console.log('data returned:', data));
```

Here, I am unable to comprehend how or from where is this `CreateMessage` coming from? in their mutation on backend the have `createMessage`

```
 type Mutation {
    createMessage(input: MessageInput): Message
    updateMessage(id: ID!, input: MessageInput): Message
  }


createMessage: function ({input}) {
    // Create a random id for our "database".
    var id = require('crypto').randomBytes(10).toString('hex');

    fakeDatabase[id] = input;
    return new Message(id, input);
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Operation Name. It's optional to declare it but makes easier when debugging.

You can read more here: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#operation-name

Comment: Thanks Arthur, Can you try to answer this question? Please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430865/writing-graphql-mutation-query

Answer (score 0):

'createMessage' and 'updateMessage' have corresponding functions that go into resolver functions for each API endpoint.

```
var root = {.... here  }
```